# Moq: Unit testing IAuthorisationLoader(GetUsers() method)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing, moq

I have become slightly stumped. I'm Unit Testing my ServicesController where I call different methods such as:

- GetRoles()
- GetDomains()
- GetUsers()

In my Unit Test I have checked that the call is being made and is being run properly and that is all fine. However I want to make an Assert/call where I can check that this method is returning X amount of users from my mocked _userList where they are enabled.

The following code is my GetUsers() method:

```
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public ActionResult GetUsers(bool enabledOnly = true)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult { Data = _authorizationLoader.GetUsers(enabledOnly) };
    }
```

I would like to know how to get this to return users from my _userList that are enabled and to be able to Assert the correct amount are called at the end of the test.

This part of my code is the unit test for the method:

```
    private User _user1;
    private User _user2;
    private User _user3;
    private User _user4;
    private User _user5;
    private bool isEnabled;
    private List<User> _userList;
    private Mock<IAuthorizationLoader> iAuthLoaderMock;

    public override void SetUp()
    {
        _user1 = new User
        {
            stuff needed is here
        };

        _user2 = new User
        {
            stuff needed is here
        };

        _user3 = new User
        {
            stuff needed is here
        };

        _user4 = new User
        {
            stuff needed is here
        };

        _user5 = new User
        {
           stuff needed is here
        };
        _userList = new List<User>();
        _userList.Add(_user1);
        _userList.Add(_user2);
        _userList.Add(_user3);
        _userList.Add(_user4);
        _userList.Add(_user5);
        isEnabled = true;
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        iAuthLoaderMock = MockContainer.GetMock<IAuthorizationLoader>();
        iAuthLoaderMock.Setup(i => i.GetUsers(isEnabled)).Verifiable();
        base.Initialize(); // dont worry about this call it is needed though
    }

    public override void Because()
    {
        TestSubject.GetUsers(true);
      // this subject is created in code above but is unecessary to include
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void The_controller_returns_only_enabled_users()
    {
        iAuthLoaderMock.Verify(i => i.GetUsers(isEnabled));

//---------------- Need to find a way of returning and checking this -------------------------//
                   //Assert.AreEqual(X (number of enabled users), new _userList.result(my result from test));
        }
```

any help would be great as this has me stumped. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to know how to make a mock return a certain known value in your test, right?

Comment: yeah basically the exception i would get right now would be in my assert along the lines of:

<expected(X)> <actual(.Web.Helpers.JsonNetResult)>